# How to add &nbsp; using d3.js selection.text() method

Tags: javascript, d3.js

`selection.text('&nbsp;')` appears to convert the special characters so it renders the actual text, rather than a space like I want.  Is there a way to prevent the `text()` method on selections from doing this escaping for me?  For context, this is a table cell that is empty for some elements in the selection, and I need the space in there so that the cells render properly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
d3_selectionPrototype.text = function(value) {
    return arguments.length < 1 ? this.node().textContent : this.each(typeof value === "function" ? function() {
      var v = value.apply(this, arguments);
      this.textContent = v == null ? "" : v;
    } : value == null ? function() {
      this.textContent = "";
    } : function() {
      this.textContent = value;
    });
  };
```

The important line here is that calling .text() on a selection will set the textContent property on each element. So the correct thing to do in your case is use

```
selection.text(' ');
```

So if you want to use spaces then you simply have to use spaces in the text, not html encoded spaces. If you want to use html encoded chars then you have to treat the content as innerHTML.

```
selection.html('&nbsp;');
```

Answer (score 41):

Use a JavaScript Unicode escape rather than an HTML entity. `&nbsp;` in HTML denotes the Unicode character U+00A0 so

```
selection.text('\u00A0')
```

should do what you want.

Comment: Using selection.text('\u00A0') rather than selection.text(' ') will be important for many purposes that require actual space to be filled; the former will have a finite bounding box, the latter will not.

Comment: @mike It depends.  If you have a fragment of JavaScript inline in an HTML file then an entity _might_ work, because the JavaScript engine sees the expansion of the entity rather than the entity itself, but if you have JavaScript in its own file then `selection.text('&nbsp;')` will set the text to ampersand, nbsp, semicolon.

Comment: If you want to go with what @IanRoberts is suggesting you might also want to experiment with different Unicode whitespace characters; for example, I found that `\u2007\u2007` yields what I need to be a character-wide whitespace.